# Stack and Queue implemented with a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, stack, queue

I am looking for feedback on my implementations of `Queue`, `Stack`, and `LinkedList` using Java generics. I would very much appreciate feedback on what I can improve and any errors I made.

**`LinkedList`**

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

    private int size;

    private Node<T> head;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size == 0;
    }

    public boolean contains(T element) {
        Node<T> current = head;
        while(current != null) {
            if(current.getValue().equals(element)) {
                return true;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean add(T e) {
        Node<T> toAdd = new Node<T>(e, null);
        if(head == null) {
            this.head = toAdd;
        } else {
            Node<T> current = head;
            while(current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(toAdd);
        }
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(T e) {
        Node<T> current = head;
        if(head.getValue().equals(e)) {
            head = head.getNext();
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        while(current.getNext() != null) {
            if(current.getNext().getValue().equals(e)) {
                current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
                size--;
                return true;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        int count = 0; 
        if(index >= size) {
            return null;
        }
        Node<T> current = head;
        while(count != index) {
            current = current.getNext();
            count++;
        }
        return current.getValue();
    }

    public T set(int index, T element) {
        int count = 0;
        if(index >= size) {
            return null;
        }
        Node<T> current = head;
        while(count != index) {
            current = current.getNext();
            count++;
        }
        current.setValue(element);
        return current.getValue();
    }

    public void add(int index, T element) {
        int count = 0;
        if(index > size) {
            return;
        } 
        if(index == 0) {
            Node<T> add = new Node<T>(element, head);
            this.head = add;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        Node<T> current = head;
        if(index == size) {
            while(current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            Node<T> toAdd = new Node<T>(element, null);
            current.setNext(toAdd);
            size++;
            return;
        }
        while((count + 1) != index) {
            current = current.getNext();
            count++;
        }
        Node<T> toAdd = new Node<T>(element, current.getNext());
        current.setNext(toAdd);
        size++;
    }

    public T remove(int index) {
        int count = 0;
        if(index >= size) {
            return null;
        }
        if(index == 0) {
            T toReturn = head.getValue();
            this.head = head.getNext();
            size--;
            return toReturn;
        }
        Node<T> current = head;
        while((count + 1) != index) {
            current = current.getNext();
            count++;
        }
        T toReturn = current.getNext().getValue();
        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        size--;
        return toReturn;
    }

    public int indexOf(T element) {
        int count = 0;
        Node<T> current = head;
        while(current.getNext() != null) {
            if(current.getValue().equals(element)) {
                return count;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
            count++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        Node<T> current = head;
        String string = "";
        while(current != null) {
            string += current.getValue().toString();
            string += ", ";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return string;
    }

    private class Node<E> {

        private E thing;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E thing, Node<E> next) {
            this.thing = thing;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public E getValue() {
            return this.thing;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void setValue(E thing) {
            this.thing = thing;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

    }

}
```

**`Queue`**

```
public class Queue<T> {

    private LinkedList<T> list;

    public Queue() {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        list.add(list.size(), element);
    }

    public T remove() {
        return list.remove(0);
    }

    public T peek() {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return list.toString();
    }

}
```

**`Stack`**

```
public class Stack<T> {

    private LinkedList<T> list;

    public Stack() {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public T push(T element) {
        list.add(0, element);
        return element;
    }

    public T pop() {
        T element = list.remove(0);
        return element;
    }

    public T peek() {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    public int search(T element) {
        return list.indexOf(element);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return list.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: The `add` method on your `LinkedList` now silently does nothing when the index is incorrect. Instead you should be throwing an exception to let the caller know that they did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

#### LinkedList

> ```
>     private int size;
>
>     private Node<T> head;
>
>     public LinkedList() {
>         this.head = null;
>         this.size = 0;
>     }
> ```

You could just write this as

```
    private int size = 0;
    private Node<T> head = null;
```

You don't actually need a constructor for this.

> ```
>         Node<T> current = head;
>         while(current != null) {
>             if(current.getValue().equals(element)) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>             current = current.getNext();
>         }
> ```

You can also write this as

```
        for (Node<T> current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
            if (current.getValue().equals(datum)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I changed `element` to `datum`, as I would expect an `element` to be a `Node` rather than a `Node` value.

Functionally both the `for` and the `while` do the same thing.  The `for` is arguably more readable and uses fewer lines.

> ```
>         if(head == null) {
>             this.head = toAdd;
>         } else {
>             Node<T> current = head;
> ```

You use `head` twice and `this.head` once here.  Why not always use `head`?  It's shorter and doesn't imply that you are using two different variables.  You seem to be writing out `this.head` whenever you assign to it.  You only have to do so when you have two variables with the same name that you disambiguate with the `this.`.

> ```
>         while((count + 1) != index) {
> ```

This would be easier to follow as

```
        while (count < index) {
```

Then you don't have to play around with extra math.

#### Consider using `LinkedList`

Java has its own `LinkedList` class that implements the `List` interface.  Perhaps this is simply a programming exercise, but normally you'd just use that class.

Putting the [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) tag on your question would let people know that you are deliberately reimplementing rather than accidentally.

#### Paragraphing

I'd find this easier to follow with more vertical whitespace.  As a rough rule of thumb, I'd almost always add a blank line after any closing `}` (i.e. not an `} else {` but anytime the block of code ends) that is followed by more code.

#### Double LinkedList

Consider using a double linked list for a queue.  That way both head and tail are easy to find.

#### Array

Consider using an array to store a stack.  Since the head always stays in the same place and only the tail changes, an array holds all the information you need (although you have to maintain size yourself) and is lower overhead than a linked list.  This is also true of an `ArrayList` which also maintains the size for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everything @mdfst13 said in his/her review, consider this:

```
public String toString() {
        Node<T> current = head;
        String string = "";
        while(current != null) {
            string += current.getValue().toString();
            string += ", ";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return string;
    }
```

In Java, strings are *immutable* objects. Each of the `+=` operations you're doing on it is actually creating new temporary copies of the old string in the process. The fix is to use a `StringBuilder` to build the string out and prevent all the temporary copies being made:

```
public String toString() {
        Node<T> current = head;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(current != null) {
            sb.append(current.getValue().toString());
            sb.append(", ");
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Also, since your `Node` class is internal to the `LinkedList` class, I don't really see a need for having the `Node` class members be private and having setters/getters for them if the only code able to access them is the `LinkedList` class anyway. While I realize this is "good OO practice", in this particular case, I think it just leads to more verbose code. I would consider just making the member methods public and allowing the `LinkedList` class to just access them directly. Finally, I'd probably add another constructor to the `Node` class that would assign the `next` value to null for me:

```
    public Node(E thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
        this.next = null;
    }
```